# Powershell console issue with function executing in action of Register-ObjectEvent

Tags: powershell

Works fine in powershell ISE, but in console I get:

> The term 'MainAction' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

How to fix?

```
function MainAction () {
    $test = "123"
    Write-Host $test
}

MainAction

$action = {
    try {
        Write-Host in action
        MainAction
    } catch {
        Write-Host $Error    
        $timer.Stop()
        Unregister-Event thetimer
    }
}

$timer = New-Object Timers.Timer    
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName elapsed `
                     -SourceIdentifier thetimer -Action $action -OutVariable out
$timer.Interval = 5000
$timer.AutoReset = $true
$timer.Start()
```

**EDIT:**

I found that I can use profile to store function definitions. To [create profile](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/save-your-powershell-code-profile-and-script-files) use:

```
New-Item -path $profile -itemType file -force
```

But I'am still intrested why powershell ISE don't need profile to store and use functions in action of `Register-ObjectEvent`.

Comment: `function MainAction` -> `function global:MainAction`

Comment: you right, this works and more convinient than profile, thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you register `-Action` with `Register-ObjectEvent`, PowerShell will create new dynamic module to host the action. Thus, as result of that, only global scope is shared between event handler and rest of the code. So, you should put all needed functions in global scope:

```
function global:MainAction {
    Write-Host 'Do something'
}

$Action = { MainAction }

$Timer = New-Object Timers.Timer
$EventJob = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Timer -EventName Elapsed -Action $Action

$Timer.Interval = 5000
$Timer.AutoReset = $true
$Timer.Start()
```

Or explicitly add them in scope of that dynamic module, created by PowerShell:

```
$Action = { MainAction }

$Timer = New-Object Timers.Timer
$EventJob = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Timer -EventName Elapsed -Action $Action

. $EventJob.Module {
    function MainAction {
        Write-Host 'Do something'
    }
}

$Timer.Interval = 5000
$Timer.AutoReset = $true
$Timer.Start()
```

Comment: I also want to add now  that it can be convinient to use dynamic module to store your functions and variables if they must be accessible from main thread too.